# Unexpected token when running npm run dev (in next.js node module)

Tags: npm, next.js

I'm trying to setup a new Next.js project.
So I did exactly what I was told in the documentation and went with this command line:

`npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"`

Then, when I run `npm run dev`, I get this SyntaxError:

```
/Users/user/nextjs-blog/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1190
        additionalSsgPathsByPath[pathsPage] ||= {};
                                            ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/nextjs-blog/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js:13:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

If anyone has an idea why this error appears, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Logical OR assignment* is not supported by Node version 14, So your getting the above error

upgrading to the latest or to version 16 will help to resolve the issue.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try upgrading your node version, as I just encountered this issue as well and fixed it by upgrading the node version i was using.

Previously i was using node14 but once i changed my node version to node16 i was able to do `npm run dev` successfully